# Is the jvm method name of function with inline classes stable?

Tags: kotlin

I declared an inline class

```
@JvmInline
value class Creator<T>(val type: KClass<T>);
```

, and declared an interface

```
interface Itf {
    fun <T> creator(type: KClass<T>): Creator<T>;
}
```

I want to implement this interface by generating the bytecode by asm(https://asm.ow2.io/ 1).

I found java method decompiled from bytecode is

```
public KClass<T> creator-9k1ZQyY();
```

The java method name is “creator-9k1ZQyY”. the suffix “-9k1ZQyY” is added by kotlin compiler and I know why kotlin compiler did it.

This suffix is very important for bytecode generator.

My question:

If the interface and inline class are stable, can kotlin compiler guarantee that suffix is stable too? Does that suffix have nothing to do with the version of kotlin-compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#mangling) seem to suggest the mangling is stable:

> functions using inline classes are mangled by adding some *stable* hashcode to the function name

As noted in the same doc, the mangling scheme has changed once with the version 1.4.30 of the Kotlin compiler, but I would consider it quite stable nonetheless. They even provided a flag to use the old scheme to generate binary compatible code, so I'm assuming it's not only unlikely to change again, but even if it does, it will surely be done with some way to keep compatibility.